# Akaunting API - Create, Update & Delete invoices

Tags: api, rest, postman, httprequest

I'm trying to create, update and delete invoices through [Akaunting](https://akaunting.com) API. It is possible to **create** invoice by passing json to **.../api/invoices**.

But I can't find a way to **delete** and **update** an invoice through API.

I use POSTMAN to send requests.

Please help if anyone know how to delete and update invoices through Akaunting API.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you send a Delete request using an Id of one of the invoices in the URL params? `api/invoices/1` etc. The API documentation is poor so it's all guess work but the looks of it.

Comment: I tried PATCH method request to send json of an existing invoice. It gives this error. {
    "message": "405 Method Not Allowed",
    "status_code": 405,
    "debug": {
        "line": 251,

Comment: Do you get the same for PUT or DELETE? Like I said, the documentation is not in a good state so difficult to know what to do.

Comment: Problem solved. The update request should be sent to `api/invoices/{invoice_id}`. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The update request should be sent to `.../api/invoices/{invoice_id}`.